# How do I query values from 1 table where there is a common value in both tables

Tags: ms-access

I have the following 2 tables:

[image]

[image]

I'd like to create a query, equal to table 2 with all the "text"-values from table1 where the "number"-value is the same.
I am still new to access, and unfortunately unable to solve this.
The desired outcome is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Read up on "Left outer join".

Answer (score 1):

The [number] fields are showing as different data types. These tables cannot be directly joined on those fields. Either change the data type of one of the fields or build an intermediate query that converts field and use that query in join.

Also, each table has duplicate [number] values - by simply joining, the records output will be compounded (a Cartesian relationship). For instance, Table1 has two 1315 records and Table2 has three 1315 records - this means the output will have six 1315 records. Will have to use DISTINCT keyword or GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.ID, T2.Num, Table1.text
FROM (SELECT ID, Val([number]) AS Num FROM Table2) AS T2 
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON T2.Num = Table1.number;
```

Although, it appears that the ID fields are synchronized. If these are not both autonumber type fields and there is a relationship, joining on those fields would be possible. However, [text] field data will not display where there is no [text] data in Table1 (e.g, Table2 records 2, 4, 6, 24). This join will not produce the desired output because Table2 records 4 and 6 will not have associated [text] data.